# Clonezilla/partclone of an NTFS partition sees too much used space

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, clonezilla, disk-cloning, cloning

I'm cloning an HDD using Clonezilla (which in turn uses partclone). When it reaches an NTFS partition of mine, it thinks the partition has many tens of GB of used space, despite the fact that the partition only actually has about 5-6 GB of used space. Why would something like this happen? Can/should I do something to the Windows partition to make it be recognized as using less space?

**Notes:**

- The partition *size* is indicated correctly, but the image size depends on how much used/free space the partition has, not the overall size.
- There's no problem regarding the drive size, or the number of partitions, or the ext4 partitions.

Comment: do you really mean the partition or disk? how big is your hard drive? When you format a hard drive some (a few percent) of the space are reserved

Comment: Are you counting the "recycle bin"?

Comment: @Debra: Yes, I only installed Windows and did not delete much of anything yet.